# git Single Branch clone has grown -- how to return it to original size

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repo with --single-branch. The branch contains just the file that I want in it, which is nice since I got a clone of 2Mb, rather than 140Mb for the full repo.

But, now, for reasons I do not understand my clone has grown to 25Mb. I've checked with a script that I found here....

https://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/

And there are quite a few large files which are not on my branch in the .git directory. A fresh --single-branch clone is again 2Mb.

I've tried git gc, and git repack -- before that the repo was 35Mb. But I am at a loss to understand why this files are there. And is there a good way to return the repo to the state (and critically size!) that it was from a --single-branch clone. I mean, I could just reclone it, but I don't want to have to do this every often!

The command I've for cloning was as far as I know:

```
git clone -b externals/pabbrev --single-branch git.sv.gnu.org:/srv/git/emacs/elpa.git pabbrev
```

This was a few months ago and I've pulled and pushed a few times since. Running this command now results in a 600k checkout.

Comment: Could you add the exact command line you use for cloning?

Comment: Without knowing a lot more about your particular situation, all I can say is a general thing about git: it really likes to just *add* stuff to a repository, keeping whatever was there before.  It does this for every file (aka "blob"), tree, tag, and commit it can get its grubby little tentacles on.  Shallow and single-branch clones keep it small to start but git's grabby nature will keep adding on to them.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if git has been pulling from the master branch, even though I cloned a different branch. Or if it is pull new changes from any branch.